# Spring MVC bind multi select with view model on post method

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

How to bind a multi select to a view model on post method?
This is the view model:

```
public class AssignEvaluationViewModel {
   private String evaluationType;
   private String milestone;
   private List<AssigneesViewModel> optionsList;
   //getters and setters
}

public class AssigneesViewModel {

   private int evaluatorId;
   private int evaluatedId;
   private String evaluatorName;
   private String evalueatedName;
}
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="addAssignment", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String addAssignment(Model model){
    // load the list of evaluation type
    List<DropDownListItem> items = new ArrayList<DropDownListItem>();
    items.add(new DropDownListItem("1", "Peer evaluation"));
    items.add(new DropDownListItem("2", "Team member evaluation"));
    items.add(new DropDownListItem("3", "Team evaluation"));

    model.addAttribute("items", items);
    // load the list of milestones
    List<DropDownListItem> milestones = new ArrayList<DropDownListItem>();
    List<MilestoneDTO> dtos = milestoneService.getAll();
    for (MilestoneDTO m : dtos) {
        milestones.add(new DropDownListItem(String.valueOf(m.getId()), m
                .getMilestoneName()));
    }
    model.addAttribute("milestones", milestones);

    model.addAttribute("addAssignment", new AssignEvaluationViewModel());

    return "addAssignment";
}

@RequestMapping(value="addAssignment", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addAssignmentPOST(@ModelAttribute("addAssignment") AssignEvaluationViewModel viewModel){

    //save the assignment       
    return "redirect:assignEvaluationForms";

}
```

The problem is in the jsp.

```
<form:form commandName="" modelAttribute="addAssignment" id="addAssignment">
    //..................
    <div class="selectAssignees">
                            <p>Assignees:</p>
                            <form:select multiple="multiple" class="assigneesOptions" path="optionsList" id="assignees">
                            </form:select>
                        </div>
   //..............
</form:form>
```

How do i bind the options added by the user in the select with optionsList from the AssignEvaluationViewModel?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show options in Spring you can use `form:options`

```
<form:form commandName="" modelAttribute="addAssignment" id="addAssignment">
    <div class="selectAssignees">
                            <p>Assignees:</p>
                            <form:select multiple="multiple" class="assigneesOptions" path="optionsList" id="assignees">
                            <form:option value="NONE" label="--- Select ---"/>
                            <form:options items="${optionsList}" />
                            </form:select>
                        </div>
</form:form>
```

Comment: I don't want to show the options. On GET the options list is empty. The options are added by the user. And i need to save that options into the database. But i don't know how to bind the select options with the optionsList from the view model.

Comment: Do you have jquery in your project? (or Js)

Comment: Yes. I use jQuery in my project

Comment: Okay. Do you want "one by one with user" insert to database or "multiple create and insert that options to database"  ?

Comment: I added a print screen of how the assign evaluation form looks like. The user first selects the evaluator from the drop down, then selects the evaluated and when hits the plus sign both names + id's are added into the multi select.